# Remover o último valor de um array

Tags: java, java-8

Tenho um projeto básico da faculdade e um dos requerimentos do exercício é a remoção do último valor de um array de inteiros. Não estou conseguindo fazer com o último valor seja removido sem ser utilizando uma ArrayList, outra especificação seria a não utilização de um ArrayList e utilizar a função Pop para tal ação, precisaria de uma ajuda, pois o único método que eu encontrei seria substituir o último valor por 0 e copiar esse array para um novo array, mas creio que não seria o mais eficiente, segue o código com as outras funções do código:

```
public class Pilha {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    private int top;
    private int[] element = new int[10];
    Pilha(){    
    }

    public int Push(){
            System.out.println("Insira os numeros desejado");
            for(int j = 10; j > 0; j-- ){
                top = in.nextInt();
                element[j-1] = top; 
            }
            return top; 
        }
    public int Pop(){
        return 0;
    }
    public void Show(){
        for(int i = 10; i > 0; i--){
            System.out.println(element[i-1]);
        }
    }
    public void Menu(){
        System.out.println("Digite o que quer fazer");
        System.out.println("Digite 1 para inserir na pilha");
        System.out.println("Digite 2 para remover o  ultimo elemento");
        System.out.println("Digite 3 para mostrar a pilha");
    }
    public void Menu2(){
        System.out.println("Digite o que quer fazer");
        System.out.println("Digite 2 para mostrar a pilha");
        System.out.println("Digite 3 para remover o  ultimo elemento");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Até onde eu tenho conhecimento um Array não pode ser redimensionado, então a forma mais fácil para se obter este controle é criando uma variável para armazenar qual é o último registro da pilha.

Utilizei a variavel `count` no exemplo e ficou assim:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pilha {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    private int top;
    private int count = 0;
    private int[] element = new int[10];
    Pilha(){    
    }

    public void Push(){
            System.out.println("Insira os numeros desejado");
            for(int j = 10; j > 0; j-- ){
                top = in.nextInt();
                element[count] = top;
                count = count + 1;              
            }
            return top; 
        }
    public void Pop(){
        if (count > 0){
            element[count] = 0; //retorna um inteiro nulo para ocupar este espaço
            count = count - 1;
        }
    }
    public void Show(){
        for(int i = count; i > 0; i--){
            System.out.println(element[i-1]);
        }
    }
    public void Menu(){
        System.out.println("Digite o que quer fazer");
        System.out.println("Digite 1 para inserir na pilha");
        System.out.println("Digite 2 para remover o  ultimo elemento");
        System.out.println("Digite 3 para mostrar a pilha");
    }
    public void Menu2(){
        System.out.println("Digite o que quer fazer");
        System.out.println("Digite 2 para mostrar a pilha");
        System.out.println("Digite 3 para remover o  ultimo elemento");
    }
}
```

Comment: Oi José, tentei aqui e até mesmo copiei e colei seu código mas ele da um erro na função Pop e até tentei transformar ela em método mas mesmo assim não funcionou.

Comment: Qual o erro apresentado? Se for no 'element[count] = new Integer(null);' acho que não existe forma de jogar um valor nulo e vc deverá usar o 0 mesmo

Comment: Era nele mesmo, e estou fazendo desse jeito "feio" mesmo de substituir o último valor por 0, mas preciso fazer com que ele vá mudando gradativamente e to com esse problema agora.

Comment: O que você está querendo dizer com "mudar gradativamente"?

Comment: Remover um por um, gradativamente. Cada vez que eu chamar a função eu movo no array e mudou k-1 por 0.

Comment: Deposi que eu editei o código acima, ele já não está se comportando desta maneira? Afinal quando ele zera o valor ele diminiu 1 do contador

Comment: Desculpe, não tinha visto que você tinha editado o código, vou testá-lo.

Comment: Testei ele, mas fala que tem um erro que fala que a função Pop tem que retornar um valor int e nesse caso ele é tratado como um método, sem nenhum retorno.

Comment: Dá uma olhada na minha alteração, alterei ela para não retornar nenhum valor

Comment: O `Pop` não deveria retornar void? Também tem problema caso encha o vetor: ao dar pop, a posição que vai ser zerada é 10, que vai além do último elemento do vetor (um vetor de 10 casas vai do 0 ao 9)

Comment: Tem razão @JeffersonQuesado, foi um descuido da minha parte, alterei o código